Find unique pairs

There is a list of numbers of size n, find the maximum count of the number of pairs such that it follows the below pattern:
2 * minimum(arr[i],arr[j]) <= maximum (arr[i], arr[j]), where [i,j] in range (0 to n)

The selected indices should be unique, it means if an index say 2 is used to form a pair say (2,5), we should not use the same index 2 to form another pair (2,7).
Example:
arr = [2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8 , 4 , 2]
result = 3

Explanation:
Sort input = [2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
All possible pairs that can be formed are:
2 can form pairs with [4,5,6,7,8,9]
4 can form pairs with [8,9]
For 5, there is no matching pair that satisfies the condition.
We cannot pick the pair (2,4) because if 4 is already used we cannot form new pairs like (4,8) or (4,9)
Finally, we can form 3 maximum counts of pairs using distinct indices, One such possible pairs are  (2,5), (7, 2), and (9, 4), so the answer is 3
Example:
arr = [2,1,2,4,1,4,1]
result = 3

Explanation:
Pairs are  (2,1), (4,1), and (2,4), so the answer is 3
Constraints:

n is in the range 1 to n^5
each input item,is in range 1 to 10^9


I tried solving this using a TreeMap:
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8 , 4 , 2)));//3
        System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(2,1,2,4,1,4,1)));//3
    }
    
    static int solve(List<Integer> arr) {
        arr.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for(int e : arr) map.put(e, map.getOrDefault(e,0)+1);
        int result = 0;
        for(int e : arr) {
            int min = 2 * e;
            if(map.get(e) == null) continue;
            Integer key = map.ceilingKey(min);
            if(key != null) {
                map.put(e,map.get(e)-1);
                if(map.get(e) <=0)map.remove(e);
                
                map.put(key,map.get(key)-1);
                if(map.get(key) <=0)map.remove(key);
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

But for 2nd test case arr = [2,1,2,4,1,4,1], I am creating pairs in my code as (2,4), (2,4), so it is returning 2 instead of 3.
I tried greedy and 2 pointer approach but both are not working.
What is the correct approach for this problem?

The best I can think of at the moment is just throwing a maximum matching algorithm at the problem, like the blossom algorithm - this problem is a special case of maximum matching.

If your condition is 2 * minimum(arr[i],arr[j]) <= maximum (arr[i], arr[j]), where [i,j] in range (0 to n). Then why (2,6) is not part of your first example answer? @CodeCrusader

What is your criterion for the "correct" approach?  FWIW, any code that produces the right answers (for all valid inputs) in a finite time is ... in a sense ... a correct solution.  There are many such solutions possible.  Indeed, any of your 3 attempts could most likely be transformed into a correct solution.  (That is loosely called "debugging".)

@ArtBindu, question is updated with more details, please check

@StephenC, I have updated my post with more information. All the approaches that I tried are missing to collect the maximum count of pairs, I observed that while debugging. So looking for what approach is suitable for this question.

Well ... why are they missing them?  You don't need a "new approach".  You need to understand why the existing code is behaving the way it does.  That should be the goal of your debugging.

As asked before, why is {2,6},{7,2},{9,4} not a valid solution?

I deleted the java tag to save this question from a lot of unreasonable down-votes.  If you really think your question is about java, you can put it back.

@MattTimmermans Last time I checked in [help] most questions should be language tagged as it adds syntax highlighting, for one. Two it shows the question to those who know "Java algorithms"

@OneCricketeer There is no such thing as a "java algorithm".  You don't need a language tag to enable syntax highlighting, and SO is not a code writing service.  People who follow language tags want to see questions about their language, and tend not to like questions about algorithms.  Regardless of whether or not they "should", it is the way it is.

@Matt Agree to disagree. Choosing at all to use Java for solving the question is itself an algorithm... Same question could be answered in C, for example

Based on Matt's answer: Sort and then greedily try to pair right-half elements with left-half elements. O(n log n) for sorting and O(n) for the rest.
static int solve(List<Integer> arr) {
    arr.sort(null);
    int i = 0, n = arr.size();
    for (int j = (n+1)/2; j < n; j++)
        if (2 * arr.get(i) <= arr.get(j))
            i++;
    return i;
}

Attempt This Online!

Ah, the half-way point is always an optimal split.  That's true.

@MattTimmermans Re-reading your answer, I see I had already forgotten about your Algorithm 1 and this is really just a minor addition to that. If you'd like to cover it in your answer, I'd happily delete mine.

I did that, but your answer is a good contribution. I would leave it.

right = iter(arr[-(n//2):]) can you please explain this. I understand that we collect the items from n/2 till the end in right. For test case [2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1], once sorted it becomes [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4], here n=7 so n/2 = 3 (rounded off), so from index 3 to end is [2,2,4,4] but if I try to print right in above code it is showing [2,4,4]

@CodeCrusader Not 3 but -3. Python supports negative indices and -3 means the third element from the end. So the slice [-3:] means the last three elements.

@MattTimmermans Ok. Btw my first O(n) attempt was inspired by your earlier algorithm 2. I considered finding for each element the number of possible partners, so for input [2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9] that would be [6,6,2,0,...]. And then use those numbers to find the longest pairable prefix/suffix. But I didn't right away see how to do it, and I didn't like the two-phase approach, and when I thought about how to do that in one phase, I somehow ended up with my answer.

@CodeCrusader And now I found a simpler implementation and did it in Java after all.

Lemma 1
If you sort the list first, then there is an optimal solution that divides the list into 2 contiguous parts, a low part and a high part, such that numbers in the low part are only paired with numbers in the high part.
Proof
If an optimal solution does not have such a split, then it has numbers a,b,c,d in order, where a is paired with b and c is paired with d.  In this situation, however, b and c can swap partners, so that a pairs with c and b pairs with d. This removes the violation of the splitting constraint involving those two pairs.
Given any optimal solution, we can apply this procedure repeatedly until the list can be split in 2.
Algorithm 1
Now that we know that we can split the list this way, we just have to find an appropriate splitting point.  Then we can match elements in a greedy way -- the smallest low element pairs with the lowest possible high element, then the next-lowest, etc.
You can just try all the possible split positions, leading to an O(n2) algorithm.
We can do better than this, though...
Lemma 2
Given a solution divided into 2 parts as above, with P pairs, there is an equivalent solution in which all of the P lowest elements are paired with all of the P highest elements, in order.
This is easily proven with a similar partner-swapping proof.
Algorithm 2
As Kelly Bundy has shown, since there can be at most P=floor(n/2) pairs, the P elements that are paired with higher elements can always fit into the first half of the list, and the P elements paired with lower elements can always fit into the last half.
Therefore, we can just divide the list into halves and greedily match the first half with the second.
That would be an O(n) algorithm, except for the initial sort that makes it O(n log n).
Let's test with the example:
[2,1,2,4,1,4,1]
sort
[1,1,1,2,2,4,4]
P = 3, creating pairs (1,2), (1,2), (1,4)
